# AppContext.BaseDirectory vs Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location will be same after publishing the application?

Tags: c#, filepath, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm developing `ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API` and have my `swagger` setup. I have added swagger documentation to my project.

1. Right click `API Project` -> `Build` -> `Output`

[image]

2. This will generate `xxx.xml` file in my project root folder.
3. Right click -> `xxx.xml` -> `Copy To Output Directory` -> `Copy Always`
4. I refer the `xxx.xml` file in the swagger config in `Startup.cs` as follows

```cs
var xmlCommentsFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
var xmlCommentsFullPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlCommentsFile);

options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlCommentsFullPath);
```

Here I should use `AppContext.BaseDirectory` or `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`?

While running this in my local development, I can see this going inside `bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\` but after publish folder structure will be same?. So correct path will be selected after publish and deploy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.AppContext.BaseDirectory` should point to the folder that contains the managed entry point assembly, whether that is `bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\`, `bin\x64\release\netcoreapp3.1\` or somewhere else.

You can [for example](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2019/09/22/single-file-exes-in-net-core/) use this property to get the actual location of a single-file executable that gets extracted from one folder and copied into another temp folder before being run.

Comment: After reading your post, in my `.NET Core` and `.NET 5.0` apps, I replaced `Environment.CurrentDirectory` with `AppContext.BaseDirectory` everywhere in the code and it works great: For example, to get the path of `MyFileName` in the installation directory, I'm using `System.IO.Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, @"MyFileName");`